# Mongoose: should I use Instance methods for making changes to a reference array in a Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, static-methods

This is a question with the purpose of finding out which way is the right way for what I want to accomplish. I'm relatively new to programming and Node.js. So apologies if I'm not using the right terminology in some cases. This is the first project I'm working on for myself.

I'm creating a small web platform on which users can create a group, in which they share things of interest with all group members.

I created a **Group** schema and a **User** schema. In the **Group** schema there is a **members** field that is an Array with references to users. I created an endpoint for adding users to the **members** array of a **Group** instance, and I'm wondering what would be the best method to add users to the specific array.

Part of the **Group** schema looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const groupSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    groupName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A group name must be provided'],
      unique: [
        true,
        'Group name already in use, please choose a different group name',
      ],
      trim: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    members: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

groupSchema.methods.addUserToMembers = function (id) {
  this.members.push(id);
};

const Group = mongoose.model('Group', groupSchema);

module.exports = Group;
```

As you can see, I created an instance method, for adding users to the member array that I use in a separate controller file, like this:

```
const Group = require('../models/groupModel');
const User = require('../models/userModel');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const AppError = require('../utils/appError');

exports.addMember = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  
  const user = await User.findById(req.body.user);

  if (!user) return next(new AppError('User not found'), 404);

  const group = await Group.findById(req.params.id);

  if (group.members.includes(req.body.user))
    return next(new AppError('User is already a member'), 400);

  group.addUserToMembers(req.body.user);
  group.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      data: group,
    },
  });
});
```

But I also could do it without the instance method, with the following code in the controller file:

```
await Group.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    $push: { members: req.body.user },
  });
```

I chose the instance method because I like the syntax more. But I'm not sure this is the way it should be done. So I'd like to know what would be the best method out of both, and why exactly? Thanks for the help!